# permisos apache xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo un problema, tras haber instalado xampp en un pc donde tenemos un print server que basicamente arroja una pagina en html donde se pueden acceder a varios archivos en csv solo puedo ver la pagina principal pero adicionalmente no carga  los css y los links para ver las demas pestañas arroja el siguiente error.

> "No se ha localizado la URL solicitada en este servidor. Si usted ha introducido la URL manualmente, por favor revise su ortografía e inténtelo de nuevo."
>
> DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/PaperCut Print Logger/logs/html"
> "Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/PaperCut Print Logger/logs/html"

Alguien podria indicarme como configurar el archivo para que carguen los css y poder acceder a las otras paginas.

Comment: ¿Cómo los estás intentando cargar ahora? Ahí parece que está intentando hacer referencia a unos logs en vez de al css.

Comment: he probado de distintas maneras, poniendo de directory el lugar donde estan los css, que es una subcarpeta.   `Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/PaperCut Print Logger/logs/html/css`

Comment: has revisado que tipos de permisos tienes esos directorios y archivos ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado, al final  he cambiado el directory de
`Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/PaperCut Print Logger/logs/html/css`  hacia
`Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/PaperCut Print Logger`
y adicionalmente cambie los linksde los CSS entre otros y ha funcionado.